# Can I access the same vector from within nested parallel loops?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, pragma

I am getting to grips with how `#pragma omp parallel for` works, and am wondering if the following code will work, or if I am not using the parallelisation correctly.

Given an input of a vector of seed solutions with custom class `Sol`, I want to generate `n_iter` solutions for each one of these seeds, and put them all into a single vector.

A simple version of this code is:

```
// input:
std::vector<Sol> seed_sols; // vector containing seed solutions
int n_iter; // number of iterations per seed

// create data structure to hold all solutions to be generated
std::vector<Sol> sols(seed_sols.size()*n_iter);

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int seed_sol = 0; seed_sol < seed_sols.size(); ++seed_sol){
    Sol curr_seed = seed_sols[seed_sol];
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n_iter; ++i){
        sols[seed_sol*n_iter + i] = generateSol(curr_seed);
    }
}
```

Is it okay to run two parallel loops in this way? and will the inner loop actually do anything to speed up the process if I am limited to 4 threads, and the size of `seed_sols` is greater than 4?

Can I safely run this code using the two parallel loops even though they access the same data structure, because there is no way that they can access the same element of `sols` at the same time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
thanks

**EDIT:**

I have successfully run the code several times without any errors, and it seems to work fine enough. However I still don't know if this is good practice or not for parallelising this kind of code.